# Expanding a component in a PopupView - Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8.5.1 with the Vaading Desiin combination with Spring Boot 2.0.4.

Currently I am trying to add a PopupView at the bottom of the page which opens on button click. In the Popup there is a vertical layout including two components: a HorizontalSplitPanel and a Button. The PopupView should have the width of the current BrowserWindow and one third of the height.
The HorizontalSplitPanel should use all the space in the popup, which is not needed for the button.

What I did:

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class View extends VerticalLayout implements Observer {

    private final PopupContentView popupContentView;

    private PopupView popup;

    @Autowired
    public View(PopupContentView popupContentView) {
        this.popupContentView = popupContentView;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        button.addClickListener(clickEvent -> openPopup());
    }

    private void openPopup() {
        if (popup == null) {
            setSizeOfPopUp();
            // popup will adjust automatically to size of content
            popup = new PopupView(null, popupContentView);
            popup.addPopupVisibilityListener(event -> {
                if (event.isPopupVisible()) {
                    popupContentView.build(this::submitted);
                }
            });
            popup.setHideOnMouseOut(false);
            this.addComponent(popup);
        }
        popup.setPopupVisible(true);
    }

    private void setSizeOfPopUp() {
        if (popupContentView != null) {
            popupContentView.setWidth(Page.getCurrent().getBrowserWindowWidth(), Unit.PIXELS);
            popupContentView.setHeight(((float) Page.getCurrent().getBrowserWindowHeight()) / 3, Unit.PIXELS);
        }
    }

    private void submitted() {
        // do some stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
        if (observable instanceof BrowserWindowResizeListenerObservable) {
            setSizeOfPopUp();
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class BrowserWindowResizeListenerObservable extends Observable implements Page.BrowserWindowResizeListener {

    @Override
    public void browserWindowResized(Page.BrowserWindowResizeEvent browserWindowResizeEvent) {
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}

@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class PopupContentView extends VerticalLayout {

    private SubmitCallback submitCallback;
    private Button submitBtn;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        super.init();
    }

    void build(@NotNull SubmitCallback) {
        removeAllComponents();
        this.addComponent(horizontalSplitPanel);
        this.addComponent(submitBtn);
        this.setExpandRatio(horizontalSplitPanel, 1.0f);
        this.submitCallback = callback;
    }

    private void submit() {
        submitCallback.submit(someContent);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface SubmitCallback {

        void submit(SomeContent someContent);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a main view, a view for the content and a listener class.
What I want to happen is that the popup is visible on button click and contains the content view with the panel and the submit button. The panel takes the rest of the space, which is not needed for the button. and the popup is fully filled with content.

What actually happens is that the panel takes the full space of the popup and the button will be shown below the popup.
However, when I resize the window and the resizing event gets fired, everything is fine and the button is no longer below the popup.
It seems to be that the padding and the margin (which are the HTML implementation of the expand ratio in Vaadin) are calculated at an earlier stage and get triggered again when resizing the window. However, I have no clue when and what I need to do, to trigger it.

Does anyone have an idea, how can fix this?

**EDIT:**
When I have a Tree component or a DateField component in the PopupView and then expand a tree element or change the value of the DateField by selecting a value from the Date popup, the resizing is done correctly and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the method of checking Browser window size and calculating target pixel size is too complex for your case. I would recommend just to set the width of the popup to be 100% and height to be 33%, like `component.setHeight("33%")`, yes you can use percentages for width and height instead of pixels. Then sizing is done by CSS, and it will react faster to browser window sizing without server round trip.

Comment: As the div container around the div, which is the popupview has an height and width of 0, setting the height and the width of the container means setting height and width to 0 as well. Therefor the container will be as big as the inner containers are and not the outer ones. So, sorry, your solution is not working, but thanks for helping